# calling a controller method everytime user changes selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have follwoing code

```
@Html.DropDownList("optionsforuser", new SelectList(new[] { "Option1", "Option2" }), "Select")
```

Now i want to call a method from controller passing it whatever option user has selected. Any ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MVC 3 comes with jQuery as it's javascript library of choice, you could do the following for a full page post:

```
$('optionsforuser').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Or if you wish to go asynchronous:

```
$('optionsforuser').on('change', function() {
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  $.post('urihere', form.serialize());
});
```

**Update**

Or asynchronous with a callback on complete:

```
Or if you wish to go asynchronous:

$('optionsforuser').on('change', function() {
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'urlHere',
    data: form.serialize(),
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      // Your callback code here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think I am struggling with the syntax here. If I have to call a method MyMethod from controller HomeController and assuming I don't have to pass any arguments. Should the syntax  $.post({uri: 'Home/MyMethod'}) work?

Comment: cuz when i do the above i get error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'". This error is on  the line s.url = s.url.replace( rhash, "" ); within ajax: function( origSettings ) in jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js

Comment: @palmsnow apologies, `uri` property should have been `url`, answer now updated.

Comment: just to be clear what is the 'form' in $(this).closest('form');.  Want to make sure if not mixing it with var form

Comment: @palmsnow the `'form'` is the nearest form element in the DOM

Comment: one more side question, how can i add a callback function in the same call?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5669/discussion-between-rich-okelly-and-palm-snow)

Answer (score 1):

attach an event handler with jquery that does the ajax call on change.

```
$("#optionsforuser").bind("change", function() { 
        // call you controller with jquery ajax.
        $(this).val() // this is the selected value
    });
```

look at [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/binding-an-event-to-a-select-onchange)

Comment: i tried what u suggested but the function never get called. Should it be ("#optionsforuser") or $('optionsforuser'). as rich as suggested

Comment: @palmsnow the $"(#xxx") will select the element with id=xxx, so just write your id instead of the xxx